# URL Rewrite query

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to understand what is meaning of these Rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html /title.php?file=$1&sub1=$2 [NC]
```

And

```
RewriteRule ^admin/reg/([^/]+) /admin.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

Kindly give me example, how it would be redirected to title.php

Comment: Two things: there is an excellent documentation for mod_rewrite and this belongs on ServerFault. Voted to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

If you went to `http://yourdomain/yomomma/house.html` it would redirect to `/title.php?file=yomamma&sub1=house`

The second one `http://yourdomain/admin/reg/candyfloss` would redirect to `/admin.php?file=candyfloss`

NC makes it case insensitive.

Check out this page for more information on Regex (which is what's used in the first part of the RewriteRule) [Regex Quickstart](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html). Regex basically allows you to search strings. The example you posted picks  up any characters except backslashes (which are used to break your parameters anyways).